# How can I get clipboard data in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

How can I retrieve the data transferred for copying via Cypress .spy() method?
Without using

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
  win.navigator.clipboard.readText()
  ...
}
```

is it possible?

Comment: no, I need retrieve the data transferred for copying without pasting etc.

Comment: no, this is regular case in JS

Comment: https://egghead.io/blog/handling-copy-and-paste-in-cypress -> Would this solve your problem? You can yield the result from `cy.task('getClipboard')` and use it as required.